# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: rest-api, force.com, integration

i'm getting the following exception while invoking external rest service from salesforce -

> System.CalloutException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Any idea about how to resolve this error.

Thanks